# HTML5 localStorage + Twitter oAuth

Tags: html, twitter, local-storage

I have a jQuery Mobile app that uses Twitter oAuth to handle login and registration. However iPhone Mobile apps that get added to the home screen doesn't handle sessions. I have been told I need to use localStorage. Here is my current code that I need help translating to localStorage rather than sessions. Any help would be much appreciated.

Main page:

```
<?php
require("lib/twitteroauth.php");
session_start();

// The TwitterOAuth instance
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('consumer key','secret');
// Requesting authentication tokens, the parameter is the URL we will be redirected to
$request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken('login.php');

// Saving them into the session
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

// If everything goes well..
if($twitteroauth->http_code==200){
// Let's generate the URL and redirect
$url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token']);
    header ('Location: '.$url);
} else {
// It's a bad idea to kill the script, but we've got to know when there's an error.
die('Something wrong happened.');
}
?>
```

After Twitter handles the login it redirects to login.php:

```
<?php
require("lib/twitteroauth.php");
session_start();

if(!empty($_GET['oauth_verifier']) && !empty($_SESSION['oauth_token']) && !empty($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'])){

// TwitterOAuth instance, with two new parameters we got in twitter_login.php
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth("consumer key", "secret",$_SESSION['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
// Let's request the access token
$access_token = $twitteroauth->getAccessToken($_GET['oauth_verifier']);
// Save it in a session var
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
// Let's get the user's info
$user_info = $twitteroauth->get('account/verify_credentials');
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should help understand what you need to complete the task of saving to LocalStorage.

http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/html5-iphone-app/

nb: see section near end of the article on **Offline Data**